# Reading value of a text box

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am Very very new to Javascript, HTML, D3 and here is a dumb question :)

So I have added a text box and button like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="count" name="howmany">
  <input type="button" id="drawbtn" value="draw">
</div>
```

and then inside my `<script type="text/javascript">` tag I am using some D3.js to draw a scatter plot. Currently the number of circles I show is hard coded. For example like this:

```
var numDataPoints = 100;
```

So when I click my button, it will draw a scatter plot with 100 circles on it. 
All I need to do is to tell it to read the value inside that text box and draw as many circles as I type in the text box, not always the hard coded 100 circles.
Thats all I am trying to do for now :)

**NOTE**: Whatever we need to add to do this, please also note that it should be still compatible with IE7 and IE8 too... I don't wanna use some method that IE7 can't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the value as a `Number` by combining [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) and [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var numDataPoints = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').value, 10);
```

The `10` specifies that it parse in base-10 rather than trying to *guess* the base.

Answer (score 3):

```
var numDataPoints = document.getElementById('count').value;
```

or if you use jQuery

```
var numDataPoints = $("#count").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem:

```
var numDataPoints = document.getElementById("count").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the JS to read from the `<input>` with something like this:

```
var numDataPoints = document.getElementById("count").value;
```

And you can use something like this to run it when you click the button:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("drawbtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var numDataPoints = document.getElementById("count").value;
    console.log(numDataPoints);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/gbjqP/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/w6ypF/

You can get the value of the **"count"** input like this:

```
var numDataPoints = document.getElementById('count').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a d3 textbox that retains the same attribute codes such as .attr("x", ect) and it works the same;

you can apply the attribute class to it .attr("class", "anyname") to allow for manipulation or calling the values of the object using a foreign object in d3 (though there's not much documentation on it yet and foreign objects don't seem to allow the .transition() method but all other functionality remains the same.

```
/*Imaging width and height being of an SVG object
width=screen.width, height=screen.height;
and rows+Cols of that of an object (using d3 conventionality
to assign document.getElementById=('inputbox').value;
amazingly adding a third dimension of selection to style='resize: none;' works
```

*/

```
var foreign1 = mainBox.append("svg:foreignObject")
.attr("width", 600).attr("height", 700).attr("x", 93).attr("y", 300).attr("rx", 20).attr("ry", 20)
.style("resize", 'none')
.append("xhtml:body")
.html("<textarea style='font: Times; resize: none; font-size: 15pt; border: 1px solid lightgray; outline: none; border-radius: 10px;' id='inputbox' class='foo' rows='13' cols='40' type='text'> Message... </textarea>");
```

There are few elements i've put within the .html and .style resize none to make an unresizeable textarea that accepts user input :)